# 'repo' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android

whenever i try to execute "$ repo init -u git://git.android-x86.org/manifest.git -b $branch" command on cmd it gives an error that 'repo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

how do i fix that problem?

for more information go to this site:
http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode 
and "Getting Android-x86 source code" there you'll find out this command in 3rd line. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download 'repo', follow these instructions:

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html